# Exception on deployment with New Relic on Wildfly

Tags: java, deployment, newrelic, wildfly

I submitted a support request to New Relic, but thought I'd give it a shot here too.  I'm trying to deploy my webpp in wildfly-8.0.0.Beta1 and getting a weird Duplicate Annotation exception.  My app deploys normally without New Relic, but after going through their install steps, I get this stacktrace during the Weld deployment phase.

Using JD-GUI, I've opened up the jar, and don't see a duped annotation on the class they reference.

Has anyone seen this before?  Ideas for solving?

The key part of the stacktrace is (I think) this part:

```
Caused by: java.lang.annotation.AnnotationFormatError: Duplicate annotation for class: interface com.newrelic.agent.instrumentation.InstrumentedMethod: @com.newrelic.agent.instrumentation.InstrumentedMethod(dispatcher=false, instrumentationType=BuiltIn, instrumentationName=com.newrelic.agent.instrumentation.webservices.RestAnnotationVisitor)
```

Full stacktrace:

```
17:17:40,140 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-3) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."crs-http-json-api.war".WeldStartService: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."crs-http-json-api.war".WeldStartService: Failed to start service
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1900) [jboss-msc-1.2.0.Beta2.jar:1.2.0.Beta2]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
Caused by: com.google.common.util.concurrent.ExecutionError: com.google.common.util.concurrent.ExecutionError: java.lang.annotation.AnnotationFormatError: Duplicate annotation for class: interface com.newrelic.agent.instrumentation.InstrumentedMethod: @com.newrelic.agent.instrumentation.InstrumentedMethod(dispatcher=false, instrumentationType=BuiltIn, instrumentationName=com.newrelic.agent.instrumentation.webservices.RestAnnotationVisitor)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2256)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.get(LocalCache.java:3990)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.getOrLoad(LocalCache.java:3994)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalLoadingCache.get(LocalCache.java:4878)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.cache.LoadingCacheUtils.getCacheValue(LoadingCacheUtils.java:52)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.cache.LoadingCacheUtils.getCastCacheValue(LoadingCacheUtils.java:80)
    at org.jboss.weld.resources.ClassTransformer.getEnhancedAnnotatedType(ClassTransformer.java:247)
    at org.jboss.weld.resources.ClassTransformer.getEnhancedAnnotatedType(ClassTransformer.java:228)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.SubclassedComponentInstantiator.initEnhancedSubclass(SubclassedComponentInstantiator.java:65)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.SubclassedComponentInstantiator.<init>(SubclassedComponentInstantiator.java:58)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.SubclassedComponentInstantiator.<init>(SubclassedComponentInstantiator.java:54)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.BeanInjectionTarget.initializeAfterBeanDiscovery(BeanInjectionTarget.java:127)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.InjectionTargetInitializationContext.initialize(InjectionTargetInitializationContext.java:42)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.InjectionTargetService.initialize(InjectionTargetService.java:58)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldStartup.deployBeans(WeldStartup.java:410)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldBootstrap.deployBeans(WeldBootstrap.java:76)
    at org.jboss.as.weld.WeldStartService.start(WeldStartService.java:64)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1944) [jboss-msc-1.2.0.Beta2.jar:1.2.0.Beta2]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1877) [jboss-msc-1.2.0.Beta2.jar:1.2.0.Beta2]
    ... 3 more
Caused by: com.google.common.util.concurrent.ExecutionError: java.lang.annotation.AnnotationFormatError: Duplicate annotation for class: interface com.newrelic.agent.instrumentation.InstrumentedMethod: @com.newrelic.agent.instrumentation.InstrumentedMethod(dispatcher=false, instrumentationType=BuiltIn, instrumentationName=com.newrelic.agent.instrumentation.webservices.RestAnnotationVisitor)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2256)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.get(LocalCache.java:3990)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.getOrLoad(LocalCache.java:3994)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalLoadingCache.get(LocalCache.java:4878)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.cache.LoadingCacheUtils.getCacheValue(LoadingCacheUtils.java:52)
    at org.jboss.weld.resources.DefaultReflectionCache.getAnnotationSet(DefaultReflectionCache.java:136)
    at org.jboss.weld.annotated.slim.backed.BackedAnnotated.getAnnotations(BackedAnnotated.java:36)
    at org.jboss.weld.annotated.enhanced.jlr.EnhancedAnnotatedMethodImpl.of(EnhancedAnnotatedMethodImpl.java:62)
    at org.jboss.weld.annotated.enhanced.jlr.EnhancedAnnotatedTypeImpl.<init>(EnhancedAnnotatedTypeImpl.java:222)
    at org.jboss.weld.annotated.enhanced.jlr.EnhancedAnnotatedTypeImpl.of(EnhancedAnnotatedTypeImpl.java:130)
    at org.jboss.weld.resources.ClassTransformer$TransformSlimAnnotatedTypeToEnhancedAnnotatedType.load(ClassTransformer.java:93)
    at org.jboss.weld.resources.ClassTransformer$TransformSlimAnnotatedTypeToEnhancedAnnotatedType.load(ClassTransformer.java:89)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LoadingValueReference.loadFuture(LocalCache.java:3589)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.loadSync(LocalCache.java:2374)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.lockedGetOrLoad(LocalCache.java:2337)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2252)
    ... 21 more
Caused by: java.lang.annotation.AnnotationFormatError: Duplicate annotation for class: interface com.newrelic.agent.instrumentation.InstrumentedMethod: @com.newrelic.agent.instrumentation.InstrumentedMethod(dispatcher=false, instrumentationType=BuiltIn, instrumentationName=com.newrelic.agent.instrumentation.webservices.RestAnnotationVisitor)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotations2(AnnotationParser.java:94) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotations(AnnotationParser.java:70) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.declaredAnnotations(Method.java:714) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.getDeclaredAnnotations(Method.java:707) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
    at java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.getAnnotations(AccessibleObject.java:196) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
    at org.jboss.weld.resources.HotspotReflectionCache.internalGetAnnotations(HotspotReflectionCache.java:58)
    at org.jboss.weld.resources.DefaultReflectionCache$1.load(DefaultReflectionCache.java:81)
    at org.jboss.weld.resources.DefaultReflectionCache$1.load(DefaultReflectionCache.java:78)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LoadingValueReference.loadFuture(LocalCache.java:3589)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.loadSync(LocalCache.java:2374)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.lockedGetOrLoad(LocalCache.java:2337)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2252)
    ... 36 more

17:17:40,164 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS014613: Operation ("deploy") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "crs-http-json-api.war")]) - failure description: {"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"crs-http-json-api.war\".WeldStartService" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit.\"crs-http-json-api.war\".WeldStartService: Failed to start service
    Caused by: com.google.common.util.concurrent.ExecutionError: com.google.common.util.concurrent.ExecutionError: java.lang.annotation.AnnotationFormatError: Duplicate annotation for class: interface com.newrelic.agent.instrumentation.InstrumentedMethod: @com.newrelic.agent.instrumentation.InstrumentedMethod(dispatcher=false, instrumentationType=BuiltIn, instrumentationName=com.newrelic.agent.instrumentation.webservices.RestAnnotationVisitor)
    Caused by: com.google.common.util.concurrent.ExecutionError: java.lang.annotation.AnnotationFormatError: Duplicate annotation for class: interface com.newrelic.agent.instrumentation.InstrumentedMethod: @com.newrelic.agent.instrumentation.InstrumentedMethod(dispatcher=false, instrumentationType=BuiltIn, instrumentationName=com.newrelic.agent.instrumentation.webservices.RestAnnotationVisitor)
    Caused by: java.lang.annotation.AnnotationFormatError: Duplicate annotation for class: interface com.newrelic.agent.instrumentation.InstrumentedMethod: @com.newrelic.agent.instrumentation.InstrumentedMethod(dispatcher=false, instrumentationType=BuiltIn, instrumentationName=com.newrelic.agent.instrumentation.webservices.RestAnnotationVisitor)"}}
```

Comment: We're currently in direct communication over at New Relic support, but once we have identified the cause and a fix we'll post it here. It seems possible that there's an issue with the Jboss beta and New Relic's Java Agent

Comment: Awesome, I received an email from New Relic support, but haven't yet provided feedback due to Christmas travel and events.  Thanks for the update.

Answer (score 0):

we had the same problem. it was a version conflict with javax.annotation.security.
For example an old version of @DenyAll was used within new relic agent. 
Luckily this was fix with new relic 3.3.2